# closeEvent not called for QWidget from plugin

Tags: qt, qt4

I create a `QWidget` in a plugin. I also use a `QTimer` so showing some data depends of time. When my `QWidget` is closed is must delete this `QTimer` but i can not because `closeEvent` is not called. What can be the problem ?

Comment: That seems odd. Do you re-implement QWidget::event or install any event filters?

Comment: Do you call `hide()` or `close()` member of QWidget?

Comment: From my reading of closeEvent, it is only called on windows.  Is your widget inside another window?  If so, the function may not be called.

Answer (score 0):

If by closed you mean destroyed, then you can connect the QWidget's destroyed() signal to the QTimer's destroy() slot.